# Convert Twist from frame B to frame A

Tags: rotation, screw-theory

(full disclosure: this is homework)

I have a twist expressed in frame B:

$\zeta_b = \begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\-2\\0\\-2\\4\end{bmatrix}$

And a general transformation matrix:

$g_{ab} = \begin{bmatrix}-0.4749 & 0.8160 & 0.3294 & -1.5\\-0.2261 & -0.4749 & -0.8505 & -1\\-0.8505 & -0.3294 & 0.4100 & 2\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

How would I go about converting my twist into frame A?

I suspect I would break $\zeta_b$ into its component $\omega$ and $v$ vectors using the knowledge that:

$\zeta = \begin{bmatrix}v \\ \omega\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-\omega \times q \\ \omega\end{bmatrix}$ (where $q$ is a point on $\omega$)

But I am unsure.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Greg Schmit and thanks for the disclosure. On *Robotics*, questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please edit your question to add this information. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. For advice on how to write a good question, see the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: First, write the transformation matrix as
$$
T = \begin{bmatrix}
R &p\\0_{1\times3} &1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Now we use the relations $\omega_a = R\omega_b$ and $q_a = Rq_b + p$. Then since $v_a = -\omega_a \times q_a$, we can derive $v_a$ in terms of all the known quantities.

---

In fact, two twists representing the same screw motion described in different reference frames are related to each other by an *adjoint map*. That is given $S_a = (\omega_a, v_a)$ and $S_b = (\omega_b, v_b)$, we have
$$
S_a = [Ad_{T_{ab}}](S_b)\\
S_b = [Ad_{T_{ba}}](S_a),
$$
where $[Ad_T] = \begin{bmatrix}
R & 0\\
[p]R & R
\end{bmatrix}$ and $[p]$ is the [skew-symmetric matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix) constructed from $p$.

I found the material of [this edX course](https://www.edx.org/course/robot-mechanics-control-part-i-snux-snu446-345-1x) really helpful for me to understand this topic. Maybe you want to check it out.

Comment: I wonder if maybe in the Adjoint map, 0 and [p]R are in reversed locations. IOW, that Adjoint appears to be the transpose.

Comment: Maybe because you write a twist by listing the linear component first?

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean. Yes, I learned to write twist as the column vector (transpose) of [ v w ], so v on top and omega on bottom.

Comment: Link to edX course is broken